# Same HTML source files but display differently

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to bootstrap. I want to use the bootstrap on my previous project. But once I included the `bootstrap.min.css` it failed, while it can work fine if I create a new html from scratch.

I've uploaded the sample files in GitHub: https://github.com/kid551/toolbox/tree/master/bootstrapSameFiles . You can check that the `test.htm` and `test2.htm` are the same files but they will display differently like this:

**test.htm**:

=============================

[image]

=============================

**test2.htm**:

=============================

[image]

=============================

I think you can rebuild this issue by directly downloading from GitHub.

I don't know why it happens and how I fixed this.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show output screenshots or an upload to live server, as on your above Github, both files are having same code, so in no way the issue can be known.

Comment: I've uploaded the screenshot. I think you can rebuild this issue by downloading it directly.

Comment: Live demo would be good, as both codes are same. Can you upload both on a test server and send the link which reproduces the issue on your end?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have public test server now. The code only involves HTML and CSS, I think it can be tested in normal environment. BTW, maybe it's the issue of these two files. I guess.

Comment: The issue can be anything, but unless it is uploaded and then re-generated, it cannot be precisely concluded. If you can check and upload to a place where this issue can be replicated, things can then be concluded much better.

Comment: Probably wrong encoding used here like @Aer0 answered below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're running into some encoding issues. Even though your code base seems to be the same - it isn't. Let me show you visually.

The moment I switch from `UTF-8` to `UTF-16 BE`, your working versions (`test.htm`) code gets cryptic, while the other one seems to be pretty well working.

**test.htm (UTF-16 BE)**
[image]

**test2.htm (UTF-16 BE)**
[image]

So eventually you might have copied your code from somewhere else or even used a wrong encoding.

**EDIT**

You can test that with any editor which is able to show you some code. Just try to delete a linebreak by hitting backspace at the first index of a row. You'll notice on almost every row that you're not deleting the linebreak but an 'invisible character' instead. So that again means, you're just not able to see those charecters your editor is not able to encode properly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I checked my Notepad++ again, and changed it into ANSI or utf-8, it can work fine finally. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have downloaded your source from the GIT. You are right both are similar but there is something wrong with the test2.htm file. I have NetBeans installed on my local. When I open test2 file its showing source as empty in NetBeans.But if I open the same file using notepad++ it's showing the source. So maybe file is corrupted. What I suggest is try to create the new file or use NetBeans. After saving using NetBeans its displaying same as test.html

[image]

Comment: can you please tell me how you have created this file?. did you download it from the internet? or used any tool to create this fine.

Comment: I create this file by using Notepad++ with Encoding UCS-2 BE BOM, which may be changed by accident. And I just adjust it into ANSI and saved, it can work.